# Как считать данные с паспорта(загран) через NFC?

Tags: java, android, nfc

На githab-e есть различные примеры того как реализован обмен данными между android-ом и nfc чипом, но там я не нашёл примера того, как и что делать, если я хочу получить данные с чипа паспорта, причём как я понимаю, нужно сначала отправлять ключ, который указан на самой странице паспорта, в secure-element, не совсем понимаю, как это осуществить. Есть у кого-то идеи?  Функционал который мне нужен реализован в этом [приложении](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.innovalor.nfciddocshowcase), но нет исходников.

Answer (score 2):

Отвечу вам как человек чья одна из основных задач на работе, это программирование nfc плат и т.п., что у карточек множество протоколов работы и каждый работает по разному. Для того, чтобы считать данные паспорта необходимо знать как и куда они записываются, а главное знать протокол с помощью которого пооизводится запись, поэтому могу вам посоветовать поискать спецификацию на nfc паспорта, вероятнее всего есть какой-то гост или ISO стандарт, в котором вы найдёте нужную инфу

Comment: вот, нашёл всё же рабочее решение http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=362220